# Android AVD no start

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am using linux, specifically ubuntu budgie, I have problems starting the android avd, it just does not start, it throws the box that says loading, but disappears and does not continue because could this be happening? I need to install some library? And install the jdk of java 8 and install the kvm but I do not know that I can not configure

Comment: Do you have any other virtual machines running?  VirtualBox?  I only ask because this is what caused my emulator to not start the other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update I had to edit my `.bashrc` to set it to use the system libraries.

On terminal:

```
cd ~/
gedit .bashrc
```

Add this line to the end of the fine:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
```

Restart the computer.